# Creating a discard poker card method in python

Tags: python, poker, zelle-graphics

I'am creating a discard method that remove one or several cards(indicated by the user) in a hand and replace them with card from the deck.

I had a list of all the cards in my list and I created a window, the buttons, and an Entry box.

What I planned to do was to take the input from the entry box and replace the card indicated with a random card;then return the hand.

However, my remove_card function does not seem to work.I am guessing the getText function did not get the input correctly.

```
from graphics import*
suits = ["c","d","h","s"]
ranks=["a","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","t","j","q","k"]
list=[]
x=0
for items in ranks:
    list.append(ranks[x]+suits[0])
    x=x+1

x=0
for items in ranks:
    list.append(ranks[x]+suits[1])
    x=x+1

x=0
for items in ranks:
    list.append(ranks[x]+suits[2])
    x=x+1

x=0
for items in ranks:
    list.append(ranks[x]+suits[3])
    x=x+1

#creat a list of all the card#

import random
hand=random.sample(list,5)

#select 5 random cards#

def shuffle(hand):
        x=50
        for cards in hand:
                i=Image(Point(x,100),"C:/ICS/cards/"+cards+".gif")
                i.draw(w)
                x=x+20
#a function that prints card#

def remove_card(cards):
    g=[]
    inputStr=inputBox.getText()
    for card in cards:
        if card==inputStr:
            card=cards.replace(inputStr,random.choice(list))
            g.append(card)
        else:
            g.append(card)
    return g


from graphics import *
w=GraphWin('My Window', 400, 200)
i=Point(100,100)
aRectangle=Rectangle(Point(10,150),Point(100,190))
aRectangle.setFill('green')
message=Text(Point(55,170),"Deal")
aRectangle2=Rectangle(Point(150,150),Point(240,190))
aRectangle2.setFill('red')
aRectangle3=Rectangle(Point(150,10),Point(250,50))
message2=Text(Point(195,170),"Quit")
aRectangle.draw(w)
aRectangle2.draw(w)
aRectangle3.draw(w)
message.draw(w)
message2.draw(w)
#drawing all the basics of the deck#
hand=random.sample(list,5)
shuffle(hand)#shuffle cards#
remove=Text(Point(340,130),"Chance to Discards")
remove.draw(w)
inputBox=Entry(Point(350,150),20)
inputBox.draw(w)
hand=remove_card(hand)

while True:
        p3=w.getMouse() #if the point is in the range of quit, close the window#
        if p3.getX()>150 and p3.getX()<240 and p3.getY()>150 and p3.getY()<190:
                w.close()
                break
        elif p3.getX()>10 and p3.getX()<100 and p3.getY()>150 and p3.getY()<190:
                hand=random.sample(list,5)#if the point is inside the range of deal, deal card#
                shuffle(hand) #change hand#
```

Comment: Unrelated—`list` is a bad variable name because it shadows the type named `list`.

Answer (score 0):

> remove_card function does not seem to work.I am guessing the
>   getText function did not get the input correctly.

No, your code to test `cards.replace()` is broken and this line of `remove_card()` doesn't work:

```
card=cards.replace(inputStr,random.choice(list))
```

there is no `.replace()` method for the type list and you don't need it anyway.  Fixing this function, and replacing the variable `list` with `card_list`:

```
def remove_card(cards):
    hand = []

    text = inputBox.getText()

    for card in cards:
        if card == text:
            hand.append(random.choice(card_list))
        else:
            hand.append(card)

    return hand
```

Hand test this code, don't rely on your current testing code.

You can replace all four of these similar loops:

```
x=0
for items in ranks:
    list.append(ranks[x]+suits[0])
    x=x+1
```

with just one loop (again `list` -> `card_list`):

```
for suit in suits:
    for rank in ranks:
        card_list.append(rank + suit)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @Jane, you're welcome.  Note that this `remove_card()` function is flawed in the same way as your hand allocation (random sample) code -- they don't remove the card(s) they select from `card_list` so a card might get allocated anew when it shouldn't.  It seems a relatively easy problem to fix, however.